# Spotify play from C# using BASS

Tags: c#, spotify, bass

I'm working on an audio player based on Raspberry+C#+BASS.NET
I'm already able to play from file system, Rhapsody and Tidal

Is there a way to play or to act as a "target device" in spotify? I would like to get the stream, and play using my application

Thanks to all
Leonardo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET, you can get a dev-token at https://developer.spotify.com/

Comment: Thanks. I will look at them. At first glance, ti seems they show how to access information and control other players, while my goal is to get the real stream and using it, so acting as a real player and not just a remoter